# text username change with timer

Tags: javascript

I need to create a timer that changes and stops when mouse is over the username i cannot edit the HTML so i have to change the username using the text below

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("a").css("visibility","visible");    
    $("img[width!='32']").css("display","inline");    
    $("a[href*='/?q=ntlp/user/profile/197566']").html("username goes here");    
    $("a[href*='/?q=ntlp/user/profile/197566']").attr("href","www.website.com");
});
```

but need to change between two usernames and i don't know how to do it.

Comment: I just made a small example is this what you are trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/X8HSA/

Comment: kinda but instead of changing when mouse is over username it changes automatic using a timer and stops when mouse is over username

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6m8Zy/ ? Odd request, btw. You doing something sneaky?